# Question about AVL properties

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-trees, avl-trees

> Assume that the oil company saves for each person that works in the
> company a record with its name, its salary, its age and its date of
> birth. You can assume that no two fields are identical for any two
> employees. a. The accounting department wants to store the records of
> all employees such that the following operations can be performed:
>
> **a./b./c./d. < not relevent >**
>
> **e.** Compute the average salary of the 10% of employees that earn the highest salaries.
>
> Suggest an efficient data structure that allows an efficient (worst
> time complexity and space complexity) for each of the above
> operations.

I was given the above problem, and opted to use an AVL tree with a few additional fields for each node, such as

i. Key = Salary

ii. Size =The number of nodes in left+right subtrees + 1

iii. Sum = The sum of salaries of all decendants + the salary of the node

My solution was to keep going to the right child until we reach a node that has node.Size = $\frac{n}{10}$. Each decendant of this node, let's call it $k$ will have an higher salary than the parent of $k$, by the AVL tree properties. Hence, we have a subtree with $\frac{n}{10}$ nodes with the highest salaries in the AVL tree and all we have to do is return $\frac{Sum}{Size}$.
But the official solution (which also used an AVL with the fields I suggested) used the AVL tree properties to calculate the rank of the node as following

> To compute the average salary of the 10% of employees that earn the
> highest salaries. We first find the node v that has a rank
> $\frac{9n}{10}$ , then we sum all keys that are larger than key(v),
> using the sum field in a set of nodes and divide the sum by
> $\frac{n}{10}$ . To find v we use the rank select recursive algorithm:
> The rank of the root is given by r=(size(left(root)). If
> r=$\frac{9n}{10}$ we are done. Otherwise, recursively searching in the
> left or the right subtree according to whether r<$\frac{9n}{10}$ (search  > in the left subtree) or r>$\frac{9n}{10}$ search in the right subtree for > an element with rank 9 10 − .
> Then we sum the values of all keys that are larger than v using key(x)+
> sum(right(x)) field where x is a node on the path from v to the root
> (including v) and v is in the left subtree of x.

Their solution seems messy and I don't quiet understand it, but the idea to use the AVL tree properties to find the rank sounds very useful and I would like to ask the following questions:

i. Does my solution produce the desired result?

ii. Can anyone explain a little bit better the procedure to find the rank of a given element of an AVL (and the additional augmented fields that will be required to do so)?

Comment: (`a./b./c./d. < not [relevant]>` If neither was *addition* or *deletion*, use of a "dynamic" data structure was uncalled for. `a node that has node.Size = n/10` does not need to exist - take a perfectly balanced tree for $2^{10}-1$ (or $10^3$) salaries to see why.)

Comment: I see, you're right. :) So a better solution would be to find the element of rank 9n/10 and return sum/size of its right child?

Comment: `find the element of rank 9n/10` wouldn't that be the very `node that has node.Size = n/10`? → same problem as before. (Try and guess *why* you are approaching the approach sketched in "the official solution".) See also: en.wikipedia on [order statistic(rank) tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

Comment: Thanks I tried going over it again and again until I understood the Ordered Statistic tree. Took awhile but I think I understand the solution now. Thank you very much! :)